# AWSCode build is not queuing builds

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

AWS Code build does not queue builds when 2 PR to master are merged  at the same time. Only the first one triggers code build and the second one is skipped. I have also enabled concurrent build to 1 but the issue still persist

Answer (score 0):

When the concurrent build limit is set to 1, Codebuild doesn't add further triggers to the queue, it just returns to the trigger source.

> If the build project has a concurrent build limit set, builds return an error if the number of running builds reaches the concurrent build limit for the project. For more information, see Enable concurrent build limit.

Codebuild will add to the queue only if concurrent builds are not set.

Refer to this [Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/builds-working.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Now I have unchecked the concurrent build option , the issue still persist , now the both build starts at the same time , I want it be queued and start only once the first one is finished